# How do you force Gravatar into displaying identicon

Tags: php, gravatar

Is there any way to force [gravatar](http://gravatar.com) to *always* return the identicon URL?

The only way I found so far is: `?forcedefault=1&default=myCustomGeneratedImageUrlHere`. However I don't want to generate an identicon myself.

Any `?forceIdenticon` param?

Comment: So... does that URL work? It at least seems to, so why are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking if gravatar may generate myCustomGeneratedImageUrlHere for me automatically as it does when user does not set up his own image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with just using `md5(MY_CUSTOM_SALT + $email)` as an identifier.

Answer (score 13):

Add `&f=y` which will force use of the default, and specify the default to be an identicon with `d=identicon` or `default=identicon`

For example:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/HASHVALUE?f=y&d=identicon
```

The other defaults available are described on the [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) site.